# subquery where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

hi there I am having trouble producing the correct results within my query. essentially. I believe the **tonnes sold** section is correct but the values I am receiving for the **shipped not inv** values aren't.

they are basically the same query except the subquery should be looking for values that only have been set to **delivered**. I the values displayed would either be the same or less.

they are to be grouped by the **color code (finish id)**

these are the results I am getting

[image]

```
 SELECT id.[Color Code] as FinishID
        ,sum((fso.[SO Quantity] * (isnull(dp.[Net Weight], 0) * isnull(dp.[Length], 0))) * 0.001) as TonnesSold  

        ,(select sum((fso2.[SO Quantity] * (isnull(dp2.[Net Weight], 0) * isnull(dp2.[Length], 0))) * 0.001)
            --count([sales order key]) 
            from [dbo].[FactSalesOrders] fso2
            JOIN [dbo].[DimInventoryDimension] id2 on fso2.[Inventory Dimension Key] = id2.[Inventory Dimension Key]
            JOIN [dbo].[DimProduct] dp2 on dp2.[Product Key] = fso2.[Product Key]
            where fso.[Shipping Date] between @StartDate and @EndDate
            OR
            (fso2.[Shipping Date] in (SELECT [DateKey]          
             FROM [dbo].[DimDate] where [Month Order] = @Month))
            and 
            fso2.[sales status] = 'Delivered' 
            and id2.[Color Code] = id.[Color Code] 
            AND dp2.[Coverage Group Code] like 'EXT%') as ShippedNotInv

FROM [dbo].[FactSalesOrders] fso
JOIN [dbo].[DimInventoryDimension] id on fso.[Inventory Dimension Key] = id.[Inventory Dimension Key]
JOIN [dbo].[DimProduct] dp on dp.[Product Key] = fso.[Product Key]

WHERE (fso.[Shipping Date] between @StartDate and @EndDate )
OR
(fso.[Shipping Date] in (SELECT [DateKey]          
  FROM [dbo].[DimDate] where [Month Order] = @Month))
AND dp.[Coverage Group Code] like 'EXT%'

GROUP BY id.[Color Code]--, fso.[Sales Status]
```

thanks in advance :) for any help

Comment: can you post also the table's structure with some data?

Comment: Make it easy to help you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ;WITH CTC
    AS
    (
        SELECT id.[Color Code] as FinishID, fso.[SO Quantity], dp.[Net Weight], dp.[Length], fso.[sales status]
        FROM [dbo].[FactSalesOrders] fso
        JOIN [dbo].[DimInventoryDimension] id on fso.[Inventory Dimension Key] = id.[Inventory Dimension Key]
        JOIN [dbo].[DimProduct] dp on dp.[Product Key] = fso.[Product Key]
        WHERE (fso.[Shipping Date] between @StartDate and @EndDate )
        OR
        (
            fso.[Shipping Date] in 
            (SELECT [DateKey] FROM [dbo].[DimDate] where [Month Order] = @Month)
        )
        AND dp.[Coverage Group Code] like 'EXT%'
    )
    SELECT c.FinishID, 
    (SELECT SUM((t.[SO Quantity] * (isnull(t.[Net Weight], 0) * isnull(t.[Length], 0))) * 0.001) 
FROM CTC t GROUP BY t.FinishID HAVING t.FinishID = c.FinishID) as TonnesSold,
    (SELECT SUM((t.[SO Quantity] * (isnull(t.[Net Weight], 0) * isnull(t.[Length], 0))) * 0.001) 
FROM CTC t WHERE t.[sales status] = 'Delivered' GROUP BY t.FinishID HAVING t.FinishID = c.FinishID) as ShippedNotInv 
    FROM CTC c GROUP BY c.FinishID
```

Comment: will give this a try on monday when i am back at work

Comment: Thanks for your help! its seems like I had all the pieces it was just the way i was putting this together. Just out of interest, could this be done the way i was doing it?